# Retrofit + SyncAdapter +Android 6.0

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-syncadapter

I have some offline data that are saving in DB if the device doesn't have an internet connection. After connection to the internet, the application sends this data to the server by calling SyncAdapter. For this calls, I use Retrofit and add the header with the authorization token. It works fine for all android operation systems, except Android 6.0. In this case, headers haven't added and I receive 401 in response. When I send this calls without SyncAdapter, everything works fine. How can I fix it?